# How to add bitmapfield at runtime?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

Hi developers I am new to Blackberry. The screen contain some buttons.When I click on a button it should add a bitmapfield in specified position in current manager, and it should removed when I click on other button on the screen.How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful info:

[How to create a BitmapField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Bitmap_field_1303007_11.jsp) tutorial.

[ButtonField API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html) (includes sample code).

> When I click on a button it should add
>   a bitmapfield in specified position in
>   current manager, and it should removed
>   when I click on other button on the
>   screen.

Well, your screen is a [Manager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html). So you can just use its `add(Field field)`, `insert(Field field, int index)` or `delete(Field field)` methods (bearing in mind that your `BitmapField` is a `Field`).